# Trouble 'ordering' data in php from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

This sounds like it would be a problem with an easy solution, but my mind is just crapping out over this issue.  I am trying to sort data from a database based on an ordering field, and updating these values when it changes.

For example,  I am trying to make a dynamic menu.  The menu items are stored in the database with an AI id, name, and order value.  The menu items are displayed based upon the order value.

Now, if I later want to add or move a menu item, say, move the 6th ordered item to the 3rd place, the rest of the items must be incremented to follow suit so I don't have 2 items with an order value of 3.

I cannot figure out how to efficiently handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your database which maintains the order rather than using values or ID's. Without more information that is the best anyone can understand without an actual example with details about what is going on in the code.

Comment: It's so hard to explain with just words.  Joomla back in the day did something similar with their menu manager.  Imagine you see a data table of each menu item.  The ordering field is a text input that can let you manually specify it's "weight", or better yet, a simple up and down arrow to move them a place higher or lower.